# I have three doubts about css, pixel display

Tags: html, css, pixel, display

Are the default elements DISPLAY block? Or is not it all kind? `<a>` is it inline? AND `<p>` Is it block?

I used a `text-align: center;`
To centralize a div and worked is it okay to do this? What problems can it have in the future?

The type `%` helps us programmers q make responsive site and say that the `vh`, see help too, but then what is doubt I used them however they are fixed values equal the `Px` is it? Even what I understood?

Comment: i think this will help u clear your doubts. if u have queries reach out to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not all the elements are block level elements by default. `<a>` , `<span>` are inline elements.
2. You can use `text-align: center` in order to make the texts aligned in center. In case if you want to make the div to the center use `margin: 0 auto;` and set some width value as well.
3. If use `%` instead of `px`, it will take values according to the device width. Suppose you are using some mobile devices say width = 434px then we have mentioned `div { width: 100%}` that particular div's width is 434px.
   Most important thing is whenever you are trying to make the responsive web page, make sure that you have added a meta tag in your html.